# data:Array[Object] in angular 6

Tags: angular

one small issue i have, how to make this code to work:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl,FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { map,share } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-room',
  templateUrl: './change-room.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change-room.component.css'],

})
export class ChangeRoomComponent implements OnInit {
    data: Array[Object];//error
    registerForm: FormGroup;
    http: Http;
    router: Router;
  postResponse: String;

  constructor(builder: FormBuilder, http: Http, router: Router, private dataService: DataService,route: ActivatedRoute) {

    this.data = this.dataService.getData();        
        console.log(this.data[0].roomname, this.data.tv);
        this.http = http;
        this.router = router;
        this.registerForm = builder.group({
         roomName: [""+this.data[0].roomname],
         hasTV: [""+this.data[0].tv],
         beds: [""+this.data[0].beds]


    });
}
ngOnInit() {

}
onModifyRoom(): void {

    var data1 = "roomName="+this.registerForm.value.roomName+"&hasTV="+this.registerForm.value.hasTV+"&beds="+this.registerForm.value.beds+"&brojkvadrata="+this.registerForm.value.brojkvadrata;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  this.http.post('http://localhost/it255/updateroom.php', data1, {headers: headers}).subscribe((result) => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('rooms');
    alert("Succesfully changed room")
  }, (error) => {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('aboutus');
  });

}

}
```

i get errors like this : 
Generic type 'Array' requires 1 type argument(s).
Generic type 'Array' requires 1 type argument(s).

What should i do to make this to work in angular 6, this worked when i triy in angular 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data: Array[Object]` is not valid TS syntax.

If you want to define the variable `data` as an array of Objects, you can do

```
data: Object[];
```

or

```
data: Array<Object>;
```

Comment: Thank you, i will see how to implement this :)